# How come some links in comments don't get hyperlinked?

Tags: support

I've noticed that sometimes a link in a comment won't automatically be hyperlinked.

For example, I added two *identical* comments to two of my questions and [one was hyperlinked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73484/what-is-the-sk-terran-build-order-in-brood-war) and [one wasn't](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73486/what-is-the-bisu-build-in-brood-war). (Although, looking at the crowd reaction, I don't think my questions are going to be around long enough for the links to work).

Does this have to do with the new site changes?

Comment: FWIW, you can manually linkify them yourself, with markdown code.

Comment: @Wikwocket is there a tutorial?

Comment: Yes, if you click 'help' under the 'Add Comment' button, you get a guide. See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33578/can-we-have-a-markdown-help-button-for-comments) for more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a URL to be magically converted to a link, you must start it like one.  Typically this means you're going to need to start it with `http://`

Looking closely at your two comments, in one the link started with `http://` and the other did not.

You can also link things using markdown, which you can learn more about on the [advanced help](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page.  Clicking the ? icon above most text entry fields, and then clicking the words "advanced help" will take you here.

This bar does not appear above comment fields, and they only support a limited subset of markdown.

Answer (score 3):

The Markdown code [wikwocket](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4890/how-come-some-links-in-comments-dont-get-hyperlinked#comment14039_4890) references is as follow:

The markdown code for creating a link is as follows:

```
 [Text-to-Display](URL-goes-here)
```

[Like so!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)

This works in questions, answers, comments, and even chat! Hyperlink ALL the things!