# How to make links in comments?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

I have been trying to get links into comments but can't get it to work. I tried making one the same way you make one in a question or answer, but that didn't work. And then I tried [these](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4890/how-come-some-links-in-comments-dont-get-hyperlinked) guys ways, and it didn't work. Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put the links inline instead of using the `[link][1]` markdown, like so:

```
Visit [Google](http://www.google.com) for all your searching needs!
```

Which results in this:

> Visit [Google](http://www.google.com) for all your searching needs!

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!